# Noob Sharepoint 2013 Dynamic vs Static URLs

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Total noob to Sharepoint.  I just created a new site collection.  I then created a few dummy pages and then added new links on the top edit bar to the new pages.

Here is my question. I'm giving those links static URL's.  Is there anyway to make those links dynamic? (ie if I use a Sharepoint site as an external website I don't rehack all those URL's to match whatever domain name the site gets mapped to).

I figure there is some concept I'm not grasping here, and the basic top link deal that comes with creating a new site collection probably has to be tweaked or replaced somehow, but I'm not sure yet what to do.

Thanks.

Comment: FOr eg: http://domainname/sites/sitecollname/pages/default.aspx is absolute URL. You can give relative URLs to the links and it should work. Relative URL in this case is /sites/sitecollname/pages/default.aspx

Comment: This type of question is a good question for http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com but not for stackoverflow as it is not programming specific.

Comment: Ken, post the same comment as an answer in a day or two and I'll give you credit. Ultimately what I was looking for was a url type helper. Skeletank I wasn't aware their was a separate sharepoint stackexchange, will post future questions there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FOr eg: `http://domainname/sites/sitecollname/pages/default.aspx` is absolute URL. You can give relative URLs to the links and it should work. Relative URL in this case is `/sites/sitecollname/pages/default.aspx`